Return root ID for all records
So I have an issue that I'm trying to resolve here.
Consider a table that contains the following:



CustomerGUID
CustomerID
CustomerName
DepartmentName
ParentGUID




xxxxxxxxxx
1
Customer1
Corporate
NULL


xxxxxuxxxx
2
Customer1
Department1
xxxxxxxxxx


xxxxxyxxxx
3
Customer1
SubDepartment1
xxxxxuxxxx



I need to return the Customer ID, and the ROOT customer ID for all of the departments (in this case, it's xxxxxxxxxx). I tried a recursive CTE to do this, but for some reason I can't get it to work correctly. Ideally, the output should be:



CustomerID
CustomerName
DepartmentName
RootCustomerID




1
Customer1
Corporate
1


2
Customer1
Department1
1


3
Customer1
SubDepartment1
1



The CTE code I tried is below:
;WITH root_customerID_cte AS (
          SELECT
            CustomerGUID,
            CustomerID,
            CustomerName,
            DepartmentName,
            ParentGUID,
            1 AS level
          FROM dbo.Customer
          WHERE ParentGUID IS NULL
          AND
                CustomerName LIKE '%Customer1%'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT
            c.CustomerGUID,
            c.CustomerID,
            c.CustomerName,
            c.DepartmentName,
            c.ParentGUID,
            level + 1
          FROM dbo.Customer c
          INNER JOIN root_customerID_cte r
            ON c.ParentGUID = r.CustomerGUID
        WHERE
            c.CustomerName LIKE '%Customer1%'
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM root_customerID_cte

Any suggestions?

Your data lacks proper structure. Your customer/department relationship should not be in the same table as the department/parent-department relationship. Is this your actual table structure or is it the result of an earlier query? If this is your current table structure, I suggest you search for and study tutorials on database normalization. If this the result of an earlier query, you need to provide the original table structure, sample data, and expected results. I would expect a minimum of two tables - Customer and Department. It would also be helpful to show some more varied sample data.

I would agree with you, but that's how the table was constructed and it can't be changed, so it is what it is.

The following should work -- HOWEVER, I am not sure I understand your data fully; for example, I am assuming CustomerUID is unique, but is CustomerID?.  Also, Shouldn't the customer ID and/or CustomerUID be the same if the customer name is the same - or are these all different customers with the same name?
WITH cte ( CustomerID, CustomerName, DepartmentName, RootCustomerID )
AS
(
 -- Find Root Customer ID ...
 SELECT c1.CustomerID, c1.CustomerName, c1.DepartmentName, c1.CustomerID
 FROM dbo.Customer c1
  JOIN dbo.Customer c2 ON ( c1.CustomerGUID = c2.ParentGUID )
 WHERE c1.CustomerName LIKE '%Customer1%'
   AND c1.ParentGUID IS NULL

),
cte1 ( CustomerID, CustomerName, DepartmentName, RootCustomerID ) 
AS
(
SELECT c1.CustomerID, c1.CustomerName, c1.DepartmentName, cte.RootCustomerID
 FROM cte, dbo.Customer c1
 WHERE c1.CustomerName LIKE '%Customer1%'
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;

Agree with @T N (comments above) -- the relationships are not clearly defined.

Customer GUID and CustomerID are both Unique. I don't know why the database was built this way, but it is what it is.
EDIT
I just tried this solution, and it did work as expected. Thank you!

drop table #Hierarchy
create table #Hierarchy(
CustomerGUID nvarchar(200),CustomerID nvarchar(200),CustomerName nvarchar(200),DepartmentName nvarchar(200),ParentGUID  nvarchar(200))


insert into #Hierarchy Values ('A1',1,'Customer 1','Dept-Test',NULL),('B1',2,'Customer 2','Dept-Test','A1'),('C1',3,'Customer 3','Dept-Test','B1'),
                                ('D1',4,'Customer 4','Dept-Test',null),('E1',5,'Customer 5','Dept-Test','D1'),('F1',6,'Customer 6','Dept-Test','E1')

;with cte as (
                SELECT  CustomerGUID,
                        CustomerID,
                        CustomerName,
                        DepartmentName,
                        ParentGUID,
                        0 Level,
                        Cast(CustomerID AS varchar(MAX)) AS RootCustomerID,
                        Cast('0' AS varchar(MAX)) MasterNode
                FROM    #Hierarchy WHERE ParentGUID IS NULL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  H.CustomerGUID,
                        H.CustomerID,
                        H.CustomerName,
                        H.DepartmentName,
                        H.ParentGUID,
                        cte.Level+1 Level,
                        Cast(CONCAT(RootCustomerID,'/',H.CustomerID)  AS varchar(MAX)) AS RootCustomerID,
                        CONCAT(MasterNode,'/',cte.Level+1) AS RootCustomerID
                FROM    #Hierarchy H
                INNER JOIN cte ON H.ParentGUID=cte.CustomerGUID
            )SELECT CustomerGUID,CustomerID,CustomerName,DepartmentName,ParentGUID,--Level,
            IIF(Level=0,CustomerID,SUBSTRING(RootCustomerID,0,CHARINDEX('/',RootCustomerID)))RootCustomerID
            FROM CTE


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
